# How does Bootstrap know if an element has popover?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I understand when we add popover on an element in html but when we use javascript:

```
 $("#element").popover({ // popover details });
```

there is no change on `#element` in html code. How can I refer to all elements with popover when there is no sign of it in html code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The docs suggest that you add `[data-toggle="popover"]` to your elements with popovers and refer them through that attribute. However, if you don't do that and just manually initialize the `popover`, the plugin adds `bs.popover` data for you (through `.data()`, not `.attr()`, which is why you can't see them in the elements).

```
$("#popover").popover({
  title: "Wow" 
});

console.log($("#popover").data("bs.popover")); //see the console
```

http://www.bootply.com/vlpB0I0LcI

As for how to refer to them is bit more complex, as you have to either keep up a list of elements with the popovers like @Tim suggested or just parsing the whole node tree with `bs.popover` data. Adding the attribute would be much simpler though.